# Find View with the Talkback focus in an Activity

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

In talkback Accessibility mode, as I dismiss the ActionMode, sometimes the talkback focus gets lost (depending on the way of dismissal). I just want to find if talkback focus is present on any visible view or not. 
Is there any Android API to detect this?